# How can I import PowerShell module at the time of system startup?

Tags: powershell, module, startup, import-module

I want my custom PowerShell module (.dll) to be imported at the time of system start-up.

There is a way to write `import-module MODULE-PATH` in **$profile file**. so that whenever we launch PowerShell it gets imported. But if some other program is calling powershell.exe with any command-let from our custom module then it may not use profile.

**Is there any way by which we can import our custom module so that any user/program can use the command-lets from it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps because you didn't fill the correct profile file. Look at :

```
$profile.AllUsersAllHosts
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1
```

instead of :

```
$profile.AllUsersCurrentHost
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

$profile.CurrentUserAllHosts
C:\Users\JPB\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1

$profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost
C:\Users\JPB\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

Comment: Thanks JP.
I see there are no files exists mentioned by you. Do I need to create them?

Comment: Yes you have to logon as administrator and to create the ones you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can import it in one of the machine profiles, CurrentUserAllHosts for instance. See the about_Profiles help topic for more information.